# How to include/implement smooth "back to top" on SharePoint master page?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, sharepoint-addin, master-page

I want to implement the smooth "back to top" webpart on my masterpage so that every page calls this function so that I don't need to put it on every page that I already created? Anyone can suggest or guide me with an example so that I can try? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Before people start loading a 90K jQuery library and more lines of jQuery code:

Create a button which executes native JavaScript:

```
window.scroll({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Alas IE still needs a polyfill: http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/

Comment: could explain more? I kind of dont get what you trying to show right here.. im kind of new with this.. thank you.

Comment: Ah, you don't know how to program JavaScript. Then that is you next step, learn JavaScript. LinkedIN Learning has lots of good videos.

Comment: I know only a tiny bit of that.. okay, at least i got a bit of on how to do this. Thank you anyway..